# How to print with PCL

Tags: printing, printer-control-language

I have Xerox workcenter 7120, this printer is on network. I would like to print `pdf` file with `PCL` command from `Linux` host. My printer support `PCL`. 
But I don't know how can I send print job on my printer with `PCL`.

I have find this document how explain all `PCL` command [pcl command xerox](http://www.office.xerox.com/support/dctips/dc10cc0470.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

PCL itself is quite complex, so it's not that easy to give simple answer to your question.

First you need to convert PDF to PCL data and then you send PCL data to printer. AFAIK, GhostScript utility can do the conversion for you.

BTW, check if your printer supports PJL and possibly direct PDF printing. That could be much easier to implement since there is no need to use PCL at all.

In general, you connect to your printer's IP address, port 9100 (default) and send series of commands (PJL and/or PCL) along with actual PDF (if your printer supports it).

Example:

```
%-12345X@PJL COMMENT *Start Job*
@PJL JOB NAME = "test"
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PDF
... actual PDF binary contents goes here ...
%-12345X@PJL EOJ NAME = "test"
%-12345X
```

%-12345X - escape sequence for PJL
@PJL [something] - PJL command