# How can I print the PDF by sending the PDF bytes?

Tags: java, android, pdf, tcp, byte

I want to print pdf directly using wifi. Some printing programs send packages as follows.

[image]

Actually, the important part is here.
PDF bytes are sent this way. (I did not copy them all)

````
.........!...*b8V}2.......*b16W....```....".tt..*b7V.?......*b0W.*b7V.?......*b0
W.*b7V.?......*b0W.*b8V}2.......*b39W....~~~.........    
.&&&...................*b10V.>.........*b37W....gg..aa...a..4..9.E...aa...abb.|...*b3Vx5..*b35W....
````

But when I split a pdf into bytes, something different happens.

[image]

How can I convert PDF to bytes like these programs?

NOTE: Worked on the same pdf.
NOTE2: There is no problem with the parts starting with @PJL. I'm adding those already. The main problem is they split the PDF into bytes differently. I want to know how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print with PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395557/how-to-print-with-pcl)

Comment: Even though the article I referenced doesn't talk about Android, I do think it contains the correct information. The PCL code you have at the top of your question doesn't send a PDF file, it sends PCL data. You would have to switch the language (using ENTER LANGUAGE) to PDF if you want to send PDF binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Convert loading file to byte array

```
 //Converting loaded file to Byte array 

        byte[] dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("loaded.pdf"); 


        //Saving individual pages as  PdfDocument 

        List<PdfDocument> seperatePDF = SeperateAsPDF(dataBytes);
```

Code snippet for saving each page to list as individual PdfDocument:

```
 public static List<PdfDocument> SeperateAsPDF(byte[] myFile) 
    { 
        //Load document. 

        PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(myFile); 

        List<PdfDocument> PdfList = new List<PdfDocument>(); 

        for(int i = 0; i < loadedDocument.Pages.Count; i++) 
        { 
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(); 
            doc.ImportPageRange(loadedDocument, i, i); 
            PdfList.Add(doc); 
            
        } 
        return PdfList; 

     }
```

Essential PDF also allows to split the pages of an existing PDF document into multiple individual PDF documents. The following code snippet explains the same.

```
 //Load document. 

        PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument("Output.pdf"); 

        //Sets pattern. 

        const string destFilePattern = "Output" + "{0}.pdf"; 

        //Split the pages into separate documents. 

        loadedDocument.Split(destFilePattern); 

        //close the document 

        loadedDocument.Close(true);
```

Note : This code is in C#. Please inform if it works.

Comment: I could not find how to do this in an android environment.

Comment: I think that this is only possible in C#, so if you want you can try it there.

Comment: How is this relevant to the question? If you split the PDF document in one document per page, you still have the same question - how to send each PDF document to the printer. This is not an answer to the question.